# Mapping substr of dataframe to new column

Tags: r, date

I would like to map the first/second characters of the column **ï..Order.Date** to a new column called **Order.Month**.

**ï..Order.Date** is a column in the data frame with string dates in M/D/YY or MM/DD/YY format:

```
"12/1/17" "9/1/17" "9/19/17" "9/1/17" "9/29/17"
```

I need to create a new column which uses the substring containing the first 1 or 2 characters, and map it to the month:

```
months = c('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')
```

Still new to r and not sure the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the column to `Date` class, get the `month` extracted, convert to `numeric` and use as index to get the value that corresponds to from the built-in vector `month.name`

```
df1$Order.Month <- month.name[as.integer(format(as.Date(df1[["ï..Order.Date"]], 
        format =  "%m/%d/%y"), "%m"))]
```

---

Or use `lubridate` - convert to `Date` class with `mdy`, extract the `month`, use as index in `month.name`

```
library(lubridate)
month.name[month(mdy(df1[["ï..Order.Date"]]))]
```

Comment: Works perfectly +10 for speedy reply. How did you know Order.Date was the first column in my DataFrame? Was it because of the prefix?

Comment: @Joeyboy that was just a guess.   I updated with the actual column name.  it is just that there are some unusual characters in the name, that I was not sure whether it is a typo or not

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a date object you can use `format(..., '%B')` to get the month name.

```
x <- c("12/1/17", "9/1/17", "9/19/17", "9/1/17", "9/29/17")
format(lubridate::mdy(x), '%B')

#[1] "December"  "September" "September" "September" "September"
```